# How to run batch file in background using javascript

Tags: batch-file

I am able to run the batch file from javascript using activeX obj. But not able to make the in execution in background. I did'nt want to show the users that something is running(console window), not as minimize also.

please help me out....

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would be a serious security issue.  I'd be surprised if you could do it on a modern browser.

Comment: But he did say "Active X", so security issues are expected. ;-)

Comment: I remember not too long ago I formatted my newly bought spanking new harddisk (the size of which I could not remember) in Windows using IE via Active X, all done through the web browser! Apparently there's nothing that cannot be done via Active X :)

Comment: Whoa, there!  Javascript (or its look-alike, Jscript) can be run outside of a browser using WScript.exe.